# Compare two array and find the count of values which matches exactly?

Tags: php

I want to compare two array values by key which will be in the same order
for eg:

```
Array1(
     [0] => AAAA
     [1] => DDDD
     [2] => CCCC
     [3] => BBBB
)

Array2(
     [0] => AAAA
     [1] => BBBB
     [2] => CCCC
     [3] => DDDD
)
```

I have tried array_intersect, array_diff functions. It returns value based on whether the value in one array present in another array or not.

The output I am expecting is 2 since only the 0th and 2nd index matches along with the key.

Comment: [array_intersect_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php) - Computes the intersection of arrays ___with additional index check___, and then just `count()` the result

Comment: Oh yeah!. How come I missed out an inbuilt function like this. Thank man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$matches = 0;
foreach ($array1 as $key => $ele) {
    if (!empty($array2[$key]) && $ele == $array2[$key]) {
        $matches++;
    }
}

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Sorry didn't read your question properly before first answer.

Comment: Nope. in_array will check whether the key value is present in or not. I don't want it to be just present. The key and value both should match.

Comment: @Coder already updated my answer please check again. And as a side note, `in_array` doesn't check keys it checks values.

Comment: No problem, glad that I could help :)

Comment: One thing it shows undefined index when the index values don't match.